# how to disable stylelint rules?

Tags: stylelint

I am using stylelints and I have some rules that I want to disable :

in less I have to do calc this way `top: calc(~'50% + 30px');` but "function-calc-no-invalid" prevent it

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/function-calc-no-invalid

also, I want to allow my less code to apply css to component directly so

`my-componet { width:100px}` so I need to disable "selector-type-no-unknown"

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-type-no-unknown

I tried to create a .styllelintrc file and add the following

```
    "selector-type-no-unknown": "custom-elements",
    "function-calc-no-invalid": "false",
```

and manyvariation, but I keep getting

> Invalid Option: Unexpected option value "false" for rule "function-calc-no-invalid"
> Invalid Option: Unexpected option value "custom-elements" for rule "selector-type-no-unknown"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your stylelint configuration object in your `.stylelintrc` file should be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "function-calc-no-invalid": null,
    "selector-type-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignore": [
          "custom-elements"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can learn more about how rules are configured in the [stylelint user guide](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#rules), e.g. how to turn rules off rules using `null` and configure optional secondary options like `ignore: ["custom-elements"]`.